# rails db structure and relationship - how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a working app that needs to be copied to web app using ROR. There is a scenario i dont know how to create DB and give relationship.

There is JobType model has_many presettings i have given.

## Edit

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_entries
  has_many :job_type_presettings, through: :job_entries
end

class JobEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_detail
  belongs_to :job_type_presetting
end
```

Job type presetting table:

```
 JobTypePresetting(id: integer, item_num: integer, name: string, quantity: integer, price: decimal, type: string, template_id: integer, comment_text_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

User need to set comment for each presetting, so i created join table where i can duplicate the things in here to join table and do CRUD

Join table i.e, JobEntry

```
JobEntry(id: integer, job_detail_id: integer, job_type_presetting_id: integer, job_type_id: integer, comment: text, quantity: integer, price: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

eg:

there is brakes jobtype which will have 50 presettings, Now the same 50 is to be copied to jobentry also, so that i can set comment for each presetting if any, also need to have crud since i'm using KENDOUI

Is there any better way to do the db structure?

Comment: Please show your the controller, models, views, and any javascript code to show what you're trying to do.  You can click the `edit` button right below your question to add this information.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill i have not done much work, i need to do the db design so need help.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Made changes, please check now whether it is helpful

Comment: It's certainly much better.  Have you created the database migrations for the fields that you listed for JobTypePresetting and JobEntry?  If so, you should post those migrations into your question; that would be a better way to show the table structures than the lists that you have now.  Also, any queries that you have for populating the views would be very good.  You might read some of the questions in the Ruby-on-Rails tag to see how others are writing questions, so that you can ask and show details in a way to get the answer that you want.  Good for you for trying again, that shows spirit!